# Lost ability to upload Files

Tags: files, spring23

I have noticed that my ability to upload files has gone. I am a System Admin. This is not affecting all users, just me and one other person who is not a system admin. I am not sure what settings could have changed to cause this. File space is not full. Could this have anything to do with the release? I have checked my profile settings and can not find any issues.
Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What do debug logs say if you open developer console? Are there any traces of errors (from flows/triggers for example)?

Comment: Nothing is coming up when I open the dev console

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is a known issue from the Spring 23 release - https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000prX8dAAE/unable-to-upload-files

Workaround advised is to contact SF Support to fix.